# Possible to use Server side PHP to edit Local XML?

Tags: php, xml

I've created a simple PHP/XML app.  For simplicity, I would like to host only the PHP files and have it save the XML locally to the user's computer.  Is this possible?

Comment: do you want the user to download the xml file? or do you want to reuse it later/

Comment: I would like them to be able to continually read/write from/to the file.  

The idea being that the server only has to hold 2 php files, while multiple users can save their individual XML files to their computer.

Comment: i think you you should consider using a database here is how to get started http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641

Comment: Thanks, ibu.  I'm familiar with PHP/MySQL setups, but I guess I was hoping this would be an _easier_ way to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offer the user the ability to download xml files which the user can choose to save on his/her hard drive. But you can't have direct write access to the client's disk from your server's php code.